# Getting a parse error with Swagger

Tags: rest, swagger, api-design, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

My project requirements insist on writing API specification with Swagger. I am following this tutorial: [APIHandyman](https://apihandyman.io/writing-openapi-swagger-specification-tutorial-part-2-the-basics/)

I have passed the following YAML into the UI:

```
swagger: '2.0'

info:
  version: '1.0.0'
  title: 'Simple API'
  description: 'A simple API to learn how to write OPEN API Specificaiton'

# Added by API Auto Mocking Plugin
host: virtserver.swaggerhub.com
basePath: /xxxxxxx/Simple_API/1.0.0
schemes:
 - https

paths:
  /persons:
    get:
      summary: Gets some persons
      description: Returns a list containing all persons.
      responses:
        200:
          description: A list of Person
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              required:
                - username
              properties:
                firstName:
                  type: string
                lastName:
                  type: string
                username:
                  type: string
```

I am getting this error in the compiler:

[image]

I will appreciate any pointers on this.

Comment: The spec is valid. Some things to try: 1) save & refresh the page; 2) delete the leading indentation and re-indent the lines manually.

Comment: Thanks!! Seems like it was just glitchy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can also try to import your swagger into this tool:

https://apibldr.com

It will also let you visually build your API definitions.